# Custom Auth Backend for Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am building an app which serves both html and a json api. I am using a custom user model and need a custom auth backend.

Here is the settings.py file:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('tut.CustomAuthBackend.HybridAuth',)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'tutapp.User'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tutapp',
    'rest_framework'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

The custom user model is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from tut.CustomUserManager import CustomUserManager


class User(AbstractBaseUser):



    first_name = models.TextField(null=False)
    last_name = models.TextField(null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    access_token = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True)
    access_token_created_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_on',)
        db_table = 'users'
```

urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from tutapp import views
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [url(r'^test/$',views.Test.as_view())]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)


urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',
                               namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

My Custom Auth Backend:

```
from tutapp.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class HybridAuth(object):

    def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None, token=None):



        try:
            if token:
                #Change this to check time validity of token
                last_month = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=settings.TOKEN_EXPIRY_DAYS)
                user = User.objects.filter(access_token=token, access_token_created_on__gte=last_month)
                if len(user) != 0:
                    return user[0]
                else:
                    raise ValueError('Token has expired')
            elif email and password:
                #Just a dumb implementation, will change it later
                user = User.objects.get(email=email, password=password)

            return user
        except:
             return None


    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except:
            return None
```

And the view file:

```
class Test(APIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):

        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        if format == 'json':
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            test = [ i for i in range(0,10)]
            return Response({'data' : test}, template_name='test.html')
```

I go to the url : http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-auth/login/ but the login credentials don't seem to work. The same credentials works when I use the standard django backend. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Give the below a shot. The idea is to return the user or `None`, and to not raise exceptions so that other backends can be utilized if this one fails. Also utilizes [User.check_password(password)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password). The password should be stored as a hashed value, thus a plain text comparison would not work.

```
from tutapp.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class HybridAuth(object):
    def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None, token=None):
        if token:
            # Change this to check time validity of token
            last_month = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=settings.TOKEN_EXPIRY_DAYS)
            try:
                user = User.objects.filter(
                    access_token=token,  # This should be unique
                    access_token_created_on__gte=last_month,
                )[0]
            except IndexError:
                return None
        elif email and password:
            # Assumes that email is unique
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)

                # Utilizes User.check_password()
                if not user.check_password(password):
                    return None
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None
        else:
            return None

        return user


    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except:
            return None
```